# Increment view count in Django DetailView

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-class-based-views

I'm working on creating my own little auction style app similar to eBay, and I am simply trying to increment the viewCount variable I have set, and display that value as the number of times the page has been viewed.

In the views.py file, since I have a reference to my model, I thought I could invoke the incrementViewCount() in the model.py in this way:

views.py

```
class AuctionItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = AuctionItem
    model.incrementViewCount()
```

model.py

```
viewCount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def incrementViewCount(self):
    self.viewCount += 1
    self.save()
```

The error message in the console is as follows:

```
TypeError: incrementViewCount() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I'd appreciate your guidance. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should override your view class `get_object()` method to increment the counter:

```
class AuctionItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = AuctionItem

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        item = super().get_object(queryset)
        item.incrementViewCount()
        return item
```

Comment: I updated the code in my question to reflect your suggested edits, and I ran into another error regarding an argument incrementViewCount needed to pass.  But what exactly should that argument be called? If I pass 'self' I get an error saying 'self' is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Make incrementation directly in the views.py.

```
class AuctionItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = AuctionItem

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        item = super().get_object(queryset)
        item.viewCount += 1
        item.save()
        return item
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).